# Is it possible to remove undefined from an array in a TypeScript will recognize?

Tags: typescript

Is there a clean and convenient way to do something like:

```
const x: (string|undefined)[] = ['aaa', undefined, 'ccc'];
const y = _.filter(x, it => !!it);
```

so that TypeScript recognizes the type of `y` as `string[]`, without having to write my own function doing the filtering? (I.e. is there a way to have the language feature that narrows the type of a variable in say an `if` block apply to arrays?)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you need lodash here but yes:

```
const x: (string|undefined)[] = ['aaa', undefined, 'ccc'];
const y = x.filter((it): it is string => it !== undefined);
```

In this case, `y` is inferred as type `string[]`. The `!!it` would also be inferred as type `string[]`, but has the side-effect of also filtering out empty string entries from the array.